# good time to manually layout an activity's view?

Tags: android

I have this activity where in I need to do some layout at runtime (in this particular instance I need to set the indicator bounds (`ExpandableListView.setIndicatorBound`) so that the group indicator aligns to the right side of the view instead of the default left.

I've got this code in my `Activity:onCreate`:

```
int viewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
int groupIndicatorWidth = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.up).getMinimumWidth(); 
mListView.setIndicatorBounds(viewWidth - groupIndicatorWidth, viewWidth);
app.fetchItems(this);
```

Quite understandably, `viewWidth` turns out to be `0` at runtime.

My question is what method should I implement/overload when the view's children would have been laid out and their dimensions valid? Basically on Windows we would generally put such code in OnSize/OnResize.

I found `Activity:onPostCreate` and `Activity:onPostResume`, but I also found this in the docs - "Applications will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system classes to do final initialization after application code has run."

**Edit**

Found this thread which has several workarounds listed:
[Android: Need to use onSizeChanged for View.getWidth/Height() in class extending Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888624/android-need-to-use-onsizechanged-for-view-getwidth-height-in-class-extending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way to know, when the size of the view is changed (ListView in your example), is to extend that view and override its [`onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Comment: A bit of an overkill for the task at hand, but hey, it works! Thanks.