# Accessing View dimensions at startup

Tags: android

I have an android View X and Y where X has to be manipulated based on the dimensions of Y (specifically, X and all its contents must be scaled up to Y without its aspect ratio being changed). I do this by working out the new (larger) size of X and setting scaleX and scaleY accordingly. Please tell me if there is a better way! If not, my second problem is - I would like this to be done in Activity.onCreate or onStart or onResume. But in these the dimensions of X and Y are reported as 0.0. Is there any way I can do this on activity start after Y is laid out so its dimensions are not 0.0.

Regards,
Steve Kucera

Comment: See if this help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356679/good-time-to-manually-layout-an-activitys-view

Answer (score 0):

Any view in android goes through several steps before it appears on screen. Firat of all it goes to `measure()` - here will be field `measuredHeight` and `measuredWidth`. Then it goes to `layout()` and only after this method finish view has params `width` and `height`. So, you can provide your own view, that will contains both X and Y, and there, while measure and layout, change width or height of child X.