# How to Get Device Height and Width at Runtime?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am developing an app in which I have to make our app to fit for every device - for both tablet and android mobiles. Now I want to get the device height and width at runtime and implement it in my code so that my app works for both landscape and portrait.

My XML file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="2" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_weight="1" android:weightSum="100">
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/letter1" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="60"></TextView>
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/letter2" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="20"></TextView>
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/letter3" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="20"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imag"  
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/previous" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Previous" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/practice" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Practice" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onClick"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/home" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Home" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/spell" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Spell" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="Content"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Next" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="Content"></Button>


        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Java file is:

```java
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener;

public class MySwara extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {


    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
    private static int counter=-1;
    private String[] mBtn1 ={"C","D","E","F","G","H","IÄ","J","K","L","M","N","O","CA","CB"};
    private TextView txtLetter;
    private ImageView imgLetter;

    private int[] imgArr={R.drawable.w1,R.drawable.w2,R.drawable.w3,R.drawable.w4,R.drawable.w5,R.drawable.w6,R.drawable.w7,R.drawable.w8,R.drawable.w9,R.drawable.w10,R.drawable.w11,R.drawable.w12,
                            R.drawable.w13,R.drawable.w14,R.drawable.w15};
    private TextView txtKannada;
    private String[] mBtn2 = {"CgÀ¸À","DªÉÄ","E°","F±À","GqÀ","Hl","IÄ¶","J¯É","Kr","LzÀÄ","M¯É","N¯É","OµÀzsÀ",
            "CAUÀr","CB"};
    private String[] mBtn3 = {"ARASA","AME","ILI","ISA","UDA","UTA","RUSHI","ELE","EDI","AIDU","oLE","OLE","AUSHADA",
            "ANGADI","AHA"};
    private TextView txtEnglish;

    private int[] mAudio = {R.raw.a,R.raw.b,R.raw.c,R.raw.d,R.raw.e,R.raw.f,R.raw.g,R.raw.h,R.raw.i,R.raw.j,
            R.raw.k,R.raw.l,R.raw.m,R.raw.n,R.raw.o};
    protected MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.content);   

            detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
            if(counter == -1)
                counter =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("POSITION");
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "fonts/brhknd.ttf");
            txtLetter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letter1);
            txtKannada = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letter2);
            txtEnglish = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letter3);
            imgLetter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag);
            txtLetter.setTypeface(tf);      
            txtLetter.setText(mBtn1[counter]);
            //txtLetter.setTextSize(350);

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgArr[counter]);
            imgLetter.setImageBitmap(bm);

            txtKannada.setTypeface(tf);
            txtKannada.setText(mBtn2[counter]);
            //txtKannada.setTextSize(100);

            txtEnglish.setText(mBtn3[counter]);
            //txtEnglish.setTextSize(50);



            Button btnNext =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
            btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if(counter<imgArr.length-1)
                        counter++;
                    changeContent();
                }
            });

            Button mPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.spell);
            mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MySwara.this, mAudio[counter]);   
                    mp.start();

                }
            });


            Button btnPrvs =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);
            btnPrvs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if(counter>0)
                        counter--;
                    changeContent();
                }
            });


            Button btnPractice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.practice);
            btnPractice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MySwara.this,DrawingActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            Button btnHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);
            btnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MySwara.this,mainClass.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
    }



    public void changeContent()
    {

        txtLetter.setText(mBtn1[counter]);
        txtKannada.setText(mBtn2[counter]);
        txtEnglish.setText(mBtn3[counter]);
        //imgLetter.setBackgroundResource(imgArr[counter]);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgArr[counter]);
        imgLetter.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }


@Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
          this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
         return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
        }
    @Override
     public void onSwipe(int direction) {
      String str = "";

      switch (direction) {

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";

                                                if(counter>0)
                                                    counter--;
                                                    changeContent();
                                               break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
                                            if(counter<imgArr.length-1)
                                                counter++;
                                                changeContent();
                                                     break;

      }

     }



    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902640/android-get-the-screen-resolution-pixels-as-integer-values check this..

Comment: this will help u. [link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Comment: yoou should accept the anser

Answer (score 75):

```
Display mDisplay = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final int width  = mDisplay.getWidth();
final int height = mDisplay.getHeight();
```

This way you can get the screen size.

Since this API is depricated in the new SDK versions you can use this.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Display's getWidth and getHeight are deprecated.

Comment: getWidth() and getHeight() are deprecated in API level 13. Instead use Display.getSize() like this, 
`Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
        }`  
The Values returned are in pixels.

Answer (score 23):

In a Activity scope do:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int w = dm.widthPixels; // etc...
```

Answer (score 10):

In the onCreate of your activity you can do

```
mScreenWidth = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

mScreenHeight = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

and later use these variables to access device height and width

Comment: if i can be frank here, that question makes no sense. you wanted the values. what do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 3):

this is how you get the available screen dimensions. This will get you not the raw pixel size but the available space of your window/activity.

```
    Point outSize = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(outSize);
```

Also you can have different layout xml files for both landscape and portrait.
Put your xml for portrait in res/layout-port. Layout for landscape can be put into res/layout-land. You should read up how android handles [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the display related information using the class Display Metrics
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

you would require

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

After this all the required information will be present in your metrics object.

The other option is to call

```
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to tell you how to get the screen dimensions, as everybody else here did that already. I'm pointing you to a [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from the android developer dev guide, which should teach you how to design and develop for devices of different screen sizes.

After reading, come back and tell us again that you still want to get the width and height of the screen.