# Is it possible to Adjust height of listview with respect to screen size when it is used with adapter

Tags: android, xml

Consider a listview contain 2 images and am using an adapter to make a sequence of them.
I wish to set the height of an image as 1/3 of the screen size. Is that possible?
If yes,then how?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you are using an adapter to set the items in the ListView, then you can set the size of each view in it as it is created. In `getView()` in the adapter you can add after you have set up the view:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Which will give you the actual screen dimensions, then

```
view.setHeight(height/3);
return view;
```

To return that view.

Comment: Maybe do the first part of code in the Adapter constructor.

Comment: am a beginner pls help me :)

Comment: You need to pass the Context into the adapter, if you don't already have a context there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to set the height. To know how, check the answers to this question: [How to Get Device Height and Width at Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10172657/1321873)

Comment: how? please tell me how.

Comment: But that was not the question :)

Comment: oh :( but i need a solution sir.