# is it possible to set the imageview heights 1/3 of screen size

Tags: android, xml

Please consider the code given code.
How to make these image heights are of 1/3 of screen size. if i use it with an adapter.
Please refer the image

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
         >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"    
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imaget"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width and height of the screen and set one parameter for both 
layout_width and layout_height of button.
How??

```
Display display=((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).
                                      getDefaultDisplay();
    int width=display.getWidth();
    int height=display.getHeight();
```

//Calculate width and height

Say For screen 240*320

```
buttonWidth=width/5;     result: buttonWidht=48;
 buttonHeight=height/10   result: buttonHeight=32;
```

Using LayoutParams object, set width and height to the button.

Now, if you run this code on device having screen size 320*480

```
 buttonWidth=width/5;     result: buttonWidht=64;
 buttonHeight=height/10   result: buttonHeight=48;
```

and so on for other devices too.

Comment: On that its showing "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type LazyImageLoadAdapter"

Comment: in that you have to pass you activity context

Comment: am a beginner, would u pls tell me how to do that?

Comment: just pass you application context to LazyImageLoadAdapter(context)

Comment: then you can use that context at getSystemService(your activity context.WINDOW_SERVICE))

Comment: youractivityname.this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the SAME QUESTION you posted an hour ago that has been answered?

[Is it possible to Adjust height of listview with respect to screen size when it is used with adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779781/is-it-possible-to-adjust-height-of-listview-with-respect-to-screen-size-when-it/23779971#23779971)

Comment: but still i didnt find any solution,

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int density = metrics.densityDpi;

        int width = 0, height = 0;
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
         getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

         //height is actual screen height
         height = metrics.heightPixels;     
         width = metrics.widthPixels;


         CustomAdapter mAdapter;
         //pass h to your adapter class and it will gives you the height as per you need
         h=height/3;
         mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,ImageArrayList1, ImageArrayList2,h);
```