# How to implement a stackoverflow like tag in android textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, tags

Im developing a food order app where in users select the desired toppings from a listview.

**I want the selected items to be displayed in a stackoverflow like popular tags fashion[image: as shown in the pic].**

In the pic, I have selected **java,C# and android** in stackoverflow app and they are displayed as independent boxed items.

I want to achieve the same string box without the **X** .

I have a textview on which I tried adding them as independent items,but not sure how to achieve it.

Any help will be really useful.

Comment: please add your code to understand what you have done so far.

Comment: you can create one text view in , this textview dynamically add in linear layout. text view width is wrapcontent, then you will get required output

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question please!

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't able upload image before , so fortunately edit option worked now...

Comment: You can go with android new material `Chips` view. check out [this](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f)

Comment: @Hitesh, I tried adding dynamic textviews , but if user adds more toppings (say 10) then ,it might not look that good right?

Comment: @MehulSolanki so is this feature called a chip?, I didn't knew how to ask this!

Comment: Yes this is called `Chip` here is [official doc](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/). also, you can refer [blog](https://www.truiton.com/2018/10/android-chips-example-material-design/)

Comment: @GhostCat I can understand from your end.Moreover I tried myself using dynamic textviews and I can't achieve it , so asked.Im just a beginner and a budding developer unlike you.Downvoting is easy but gaining reputation is challeging for me.I came here with a query and a small guidance.Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to build using `Chip`, check below some code snippet.

Add below code in your .xml

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/filter_chip_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/filter_chip_txt">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/filter_chip"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Dogs"/>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/filter_chip2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Cats"/>
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

inside your .java

```
 ChipGroup filterChipGroup = findViewById(R.id.filter_chip_group);
    Chip filterChip = findViewById(R.id.filter_chip);
    Chip filterChip2 = findViewById(R.id.filter_chip2);
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener filterChipListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i(TAG, buttonView.getId() + "");
        }
    };
    filterChip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterChipListener);
    filterChip2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(filterChipListener);
```

I hope this will help to achive what you expect.

Comment: Thanks man!!, Just a small doubt , how to make sure that the margin we add in the layouts remains the same in all the devices?, say marginTop = 200dp, in different devices , the UI looks different!, any idea on this pls?

Comment: This is an uncertain situation where all device has different resolution, but check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710777/how-to-position-the-view-with-margin-that-will-look-same-for-all-devices), May that will help you

Comment: Thanks dude!!, one question on chips, is there a way I can bring all chips to the right with less gap between them?

Comment: Could you have a look at this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174608/how-to-align-android-chips-to-the-end-in-chipgroup