# android:background not reflected in view with layout weight

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight, android-background

I have a simple `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and a normal view having layout weights 0.55 and 0.45 respectively.

I wasn't able to split unless I gave a `weightsum` to my `LinearLayout`.

After having my `LinearLayout` split, I tried to give a background color to 
my view but its not reflecting.

Below is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight=".55"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <View
        android:layout_weight=".45dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        ></View>

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't understand what shall be changed such that, I can split the views 
correctly and set the background color. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `"android:layout_weight=".45dp"` to `"android:layout_weight=".45"`

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_weight=".55"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />

 <View
    android:layout_weight=".45"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Such an error!! But thanks dude!! is weightsum option mandatory??

Comment: Yes we can use the weight without defining the weight sum in parent. IN that case the total weight of the child is calculated by adding the weight of each child.

Comment: if you get your answer so approve  it... Thank you

Comment: cool !, if u don't mind, I have an alignment issue which I have raised separately.could u have a look at it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174608/how-to-align-android-chips-to-the-end-in-chipgroup/56179285#56179285

Comment: @adi `weightsum` specify the Parts of weight regardless of view is Visible or Not  . If you specify it and make any Child `GONE` that space will be blank . If you do not specify it then it will divide according to visible Views.. Cappese ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174608/how-to-align-android-chips-to-the-end-in-chipgroup/56238065#56238065