# how to detect a pixel/colors in the screen

Tags: android, pixel, detection

Im trying to do a trigger for a image when a specific kind of pixels appaer in the screen it show some message, when the people move the image out of the screen and the pixel go out of the view, the apk just alert "you are far to discover", but i have no idea how to detect the pixel, is there any example or tutorial?

Comment: I din't understand, you you want to get the color value of a pixel?

Comment: Need more clarification. Incomplete description, doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not into android development but searching through the internet, i have found a solution..This can be done with [onsizechanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).You will get the value of zero if the view hasnt initialzed yet ..For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902640/android-get-the-screen-resolution-pixels-as-integer-values).