# make x y work the same on all devices android studio

Tags: java, android, layout, coordinates

I just began to develop a app with java, and I only got some experience in C. In my code in Activity.java (in android studio) I got things like, just to give some examples:

```
    meteorite1.setX(meteoritePlacementX(meteorite1.getX()));
    meteorite1.setY(-2000);
    gnome.setX(330);
    gnome.setY(800);
    meteorite2.setX(meteoritePlacementX(meteorite2.getX()));
    meteorite2.setY(meteoritePlacementY(meteorite1.getY()));
    meteorite3.setX(meteoritePlacementX(meteorite3.getX()));
    meteorite3.setY(meteoritePlacementY(meteorite2.getY()));
    meteorite4.setX(meteoritePlacementX(meteorite4.getX()));
    meteorite4.setY(meteoritePlacementY(meteorite3.getY()));
    meteorite5.setX(meteoritePlacementX(meteorite5.getX()));
    meteorite5.setY(meteoritePlacementY(meteorite4.getY()));

    meteoritedestruction1.setX(0);
    meteoritedestruction1.setY(-2000);
    meteoritedestruction2.setX(0);
    meteoritedestruction2.setY(-2000);
    meteoritedestruction3.setX(0);
    meteoritedestruction3.setY(-2000);
    meteoritedestruction4.setX(0);
    meteoritedestruction4.setY(-2000);
    meteoritedestruction5.setX(0);
    meteoritedestruction5.setY(-2000);

    star1.setX(300);
    star2.setX(150);
    star3.setX(50);
    star4.setX(500);
    star5.setX(600);
    star6.setX(350);
    star7.setX(80);
    star8.setX(450);
    tinystar1.setX(302);
    tinystar2.setX(240);
    tinystar3.setX(57);
    tinystar4.setX(660);
    tinystar5.setX(400);

    star1.setY(300);
    star2.setY(-300);
    star3.setY(-100);
    star4.setY(100);
    star5.setY(300);
    star6.setY(500);
    star7.setY(700);
    star8.setY(900);
    tinystar1.setY(300);
    tinystar2.setY(-400);
    tinystar3.setY(-200);
    tinystar4.setY(150);
    tinystar5.setY(30);
```

and

```
public float meteoritePlacementX(float X){

    float MeteoriteNewX = 0f;

    int random = (int )(Math.random() * 480 - 50);

    MeteoriteNewX = random;

    return MeteoriteNewX;
}
```

Which workes fine, but just on my phone (720 x 1280 pixels (~294 ppi pixel density)) which I tested my code at. Now I published my app, but on other device, the layout of the app is totally out of sync (which makes sense to me now, cause x and y are different for every screen). Buttons and pictures workes fine, but moving object like

```
meteorite1.setY(meteorite1.getY() + 20);
```

where I use x and y are broken on other devices. I use the relative layout.

So long story short; Is there a way to change x and y, so it becomes relative to the screen? Otherwise I need to change the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general using placement based on hard coded pixel values is not a good practice. Not only would this break with backwards compatibility but also think about what you would have to do when 2k+ phones come out, you would need an entire refactor. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902640/android-get-the-screen-resolution-pixels-as-integer-values) question and the answer by Guillaume Perrot you can get get the maximum and minimum pixel values relative to the user's phone and use those instead of the 480 - 50 and your star set functions.
For the movement do

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); // the results will be higher than using the activity context object or the getWindowManager() shortcut
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int maxWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
//Make this percentage whatever you want
float movementPercentage = 0.02
//Will move the object 2 percent up the y axis 
meteorite1.setY(meteorite1.getY() + maxWidth*movementPercentage);
```

Comment: Yea you are totally right! But if I change the values of x and y, I make it compatibel with another device, but my orginal device can't run the app normally, am I right? How can I replace like meteorite1.setY(meteorite1.getY() + 20);  so it becomes relative? With dpi?

Comment: @KingRool Updated my answer